# Page can't be displayed when accessing Report Server in another computer

Tags: reporting-services, reportserver

need some help guys, I have set up a report server in a Windows 10 client, and I have successfully set it up and I can access it locally, but when I try to access the report from another computer, it only shows "Page can't be displayed".

- Things that I have done:

  1. set up a firewall to allow port used by report server.
  2. added the Report Server URL in the trusted sites
  3. configure the .config file of report server in different authentication

but to no avail, still all other computer with in the local network can't access the report server.

PS: I am using SSRS 2014

Comment: any help please, I am stuck

Comment: 1. make sure you can ping the server from the client

2. make sure the port  is open (default is 80 I think)

Comment: @AlanSchofield yes, I can ping the server, and yes the port is open, I have also tried using other port and open it in firewall, still they can't reach the report server